# How does validationgroup work with LinkButton?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have LinkButton on my page and they are causing validation each time I click one of them. I know that **validationgroup** property prevents validation on each postback. Unfortunatelly, I don't see any validationgroup property for LinkButton. Is there any other way to get to same result?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: are you looking for CausesValidation attribute ? ValidationGroup is used to organize validation controls on a page as a set.

Comment: visual studio might not be detecting that, but you can type it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not clearly understand you question.

`ValidationGroup is used to organize validation controls on a page as a set.` For example If you want to perform validation on some controls on your web form then you assign the same `ValidationGroup` name to all the validation controls.
Read the following post on MSDN it will clear your concept about ValidationGroups.
[MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you want to cancel the Validation performed on link Button then set its `CausesValidation property to false`.

Comment: I didn't design the page. To me it looks like for this page, LinkButton are playing the same role as regular button. So, when a certain linkButton is clicked, I'd like to validate just a certain group of textboxes not all of them. etc. What jou explained earlier.

Comment: @Richard77 Specify a ValidationGroup like ValidationGroup="myValidation" to each textbox control and the linkButton.

Answer (score 1):

ValidationGroup is in fact a property of the LinkButton.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx

Comment: perhaps you need to set CausesValidation to true?

Comment: I set the LinkButton that I didn't wont validation for, and they stopped validation. But it looks like there's not a notion of Group validation like avec the GroupeValidation where a groupe of controls are concerned when a button is clicked. It's just all or nothing. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Be sure the ValidationGroup property is set to the same value for all the controls you want validation to run against. So as long as your button causes validation, and the ValidationGroup property is set appropriately, it should only cause the validators to fire for specified group.